# How are linked rings homeomorphic to seperated links?

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently reading "Geometry, Topology and Physics" by Mikio Nakahara. In his book there the following exercise:

> Show that two figure in figure 2.109(b) [see below] are homeomorphic to each other. Find how to unlink the right figure in $ \mathbb{R}^4$.

The figure in question is:

[image]

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. I guess I need to show that every point in space is in the same equivalence class, but I don't know how one would do that.

Any hint for me to get started on this problem are much appreciated.

Comment: What is the figure? Is it the two knots or the complement of the two knots?

Comment: They clearly are.. but embed them in $\mathbb{R^4}$ and use the fourth coordinate to unlink the second one.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I think they are two rings. On the left, they are separated and on the right they are interlinked.

Comment: @M.B. I'm not sure if I can follow you. Is there a mathematical way to show this, or can this only be approached from an intuitive point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that these are *two* questions.

One is to show that the two figures are homeomorphic. This is trivial: just take a homeomorphism from one ring on the left to one ring on the right and an homeomorphism from the other ring on the left to the other ring on the right. Combine those two homeomorphism to a map from the two rings on the left to the two rings on the right; that's an homeomorphism as well. It is important to realize that the ambient space (the ${\mathbb R}^3$) doesn't play a role!

The other question is to argue that there is a homotopy $[0,1] \times (S^1 \sqcup S^1) \to {\mathbb R}^4$ such that (the image of) $(0,-,-) \colon (S^1 \sqcup S^1) \to {\mathbb R}^4$ is the left rings and (the image of) $(1,-,-) \colon S^1 \sqcup S^1 \to {\mathbb R}^4$ is the right rings. Assuming the left and right rings are really embedded in ${\mathbb R}^3 \times \{0\}$, use the 4th coordinate to lift one of the two rings in the figure on the left to the $(-,-,-,1)$ plane; then move it over to the location of the corresponding ring in the figure on the right; then move it back to the $(-,-,-,0)$ plane.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I need to think a bit about it. Just to clarify: for the first question; are you using the fact that a composite map of two homeomorphisms is again a homeomorphism? Your answer to the second is difficult for me to understand. Are you proving that both topological spaces are simply connected?

Comment: For the first: yes, if we're talking about the same notion of composition. There is one hmf $f_1 \colon X_1 \to Y_1$ from one ring to another and another hmf $f_2 \colon X_2 \to Y_2$ from the other ring to another. These combine to a map $X_1 \cup X_2 \to Y_1 \cup Y_2$. (Note that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are disjoint). Formally, at this point you need to refer to the ambient space ${\mathbb R}^3$ to argue that $X_1 \cup X_2$ and $Y_1 \cup Y_2$ are topological sums. Then it follows that it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: For the second, I'm first (semi-)formally writing down what it means to *unlink* the figure on the right. Instead of representing two rings as subsets of ${\mathbb R}^3$ (or ${\mathbb R}^4$), see them as maps $S^1 \sqcup S^1 \to {\mathbb R}^3 \times \{0\}$. Now the point is to argue that there is a homotopy from one map to the other using the freedom offered by the fourth coordinate.

Comment: Although I'm not 100% comfortable about the problem and the answer, you have given me enough stuff to think about so thanks! I might one day come back and ask you more questions though ;).

Comment: I'll be around. :-)